# Why isn't my function squeeze printing anything?

Tags: c, string, copy

Exercise 2-4. Write an alternative version of squeeze(s1,s2) that deletes each character in s1 that matches any character in the string s2. This is from K&R.

Can someone please tell me why my code is not printing anything? Ive tried everything & don't know how to use GDB. Thanks a lot!

EDIT: okay, i was just missing a i++ and it worked. What are you guys talking about? I have a print statement in main...
    #include

```
void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[]);

int main() {
  char s1[100] = "hello";
  char s2[100] = "pencil";
  squeeze(s1, s2);
  printf("s1 revised: %s\n", s1);
  return 0;
}

void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[]) {
  int i, j, k;
  i = k = j = 0;

  while (s1[i] != '\0') {
    for (j = 0; s2[j] != '\0'; j++) {
      if (s1[i] == s2[j]) {
        k = i;
        while (s1[k] != '\0') {
          s1[k] = s1[(k + 1)];
          //printf("***");
          if (s1[k] == '\0') {
            break;
          }
          k++;
        }
        break;
      }
      else {
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no function call in `squeeze`, and specifically no print statement . What do you expect?

Comment: @Deduplicator: There *is* a call to `squeeze` in `main`, and there *is* a print statement in it, but it is commented out.

Comment: Maybe explain what output you expect, and what output you see.

Comment: how is there no function call. There is one in main(). Thanks tho guys. appreciate it if you guys aren't trolling me

Comment: @slee0743 You have an "infinite loop", see my answer -- so, it never gets to the printf in main.

Comment: Exxercise 2-4 ... looks like someone is asking us to do their homework

Comment: He did 99% of it.  He just has a wee bug.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop var `i` is never incremented.

Here is your squeeze with i properly managed.
The two changed lines have comments.

```
void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[]) {
  int i, j, k;
  i = k = j = 0;

  for ( ; s1[i] != '\0'; i++) {            /* INCREMENT i */
    for (j = 0; s2[j] != '\0'; j++) {
      if (s1[i] == s2[j]) {
        k = i;
        while (s1[k] != '\0') {
          s1[k] = s1[(k + 1)];
          /* printf("***"); */
          if (s1[k] == '\0') {
            break;
          }
          k++;
        }
        --i;                               /* BACK UP */
        break;
      }
      else {
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the only line that contains any kind of statement that prints is commented out.

Comment: there's a print statement in main? I just fixed my program.

Comment: @slee0743 This is your question: "Why isn't my function squeeze printing anything?". This answers that question. Learn to ask.

Comment: thanks everyone! new user here on stack; ill make my questions a lot more explicit next time. thanks a lot though! really do appreciate the help